# How to get higher value without variable reset to zero?

Tags: javascript, jquery, count

I have a quiz, and I'm trying to know how many answer I have for a, b and c, d, e. I need to show an answer depending of the highest result (a.. bc.. etc)

I have defined my variables before the loop. But I don't understand why it always reset to zero. I have inspect my variables. They start at 0, after the loop, I see them have new numbers. So its working, but right after, when I use the callback, they have all value reset to zero.

I have tried to define the variables outside my `$("#quizz").submit(function( event )`. Still not working, the variables doesn't change at all, they stay at 0. I have tried to set the variables outside the ready = function(). Same thing, not working at all.

So there's something I don't understand. Why the variables always reset to zero. This is the farthest I was able to go.

```
ready = function() {

  // Init     $.fn.getMax();

  $("#quizz").submit(function( event ) {

    event.preventDefault();

    var a = 0;
    var bc = 0;
    var d = 0;
    var e = 0;

    $("input[type=radio]:checked").each(function() {
      if ($(this).val() == "1"){
        a++;
      }else if ($(this).val() == "2" || $(this).val() == "3"){
        bc++;
      }else if ($(this).val() == "4"){
        d++;
      }else {
        e++;
      }
    }, $.fn.getMax());   }); };

$(document).ready(ready); $(document).on('page:load', ready);

$.fn.getMax = function(){
  var numbers_array = [a, bc, d, e];
  var biggest = Math.max.apply( null, numbers_array );
   alert(biggest);
};
```

Comment: because every time you click send this code gets executed`$(document).ready(ready);` and `$(document).on('page:load', ready);
` remember that submit commonly reload the page... so I believe that is your problem...

Answer (score 1):

Because this:

```
  $("#quizz").submit(function( event ) {
                         ^^^^^^^
     var a = 0;
```

Your `a` is a LOCAL variable within this `function (event)` closure you're defining. It's not a global variable, therefore will not exist anywhere other than inside that closure.

If you want to use those variables as globals, they must be defined first in the global scope:

```
var a,b,c,d;
$('#quizz').etc...;
$.fn.max = etc....
```

Comment: But, like I said in my first comment, I have already tried to set the variables outside my $('#quizz') function, and it still not working. The variables doesnt change at all, they stay at 0.

Comment: the move the initialization out of your submit handler as well. You keep RESETTING them to zero every time a submit occurs.

Comment: If I set the variables outside, I have : Uncaught ReferenceError: a is not defined in my $.fn.getMax = function()

Also, I only submit my form one time, so it's not suppose to reset them. I know that if I send another form, it will reset the whole thing because I set my variables to 0.

Or I don't understand what you mean, sorry :s

Comment: Actually, I forgot to set my variables as arguments in my callback function. That's why my variables was always set to 0 :)

Thanks for the help !